# Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict?

Tags: packages, best-practices, theorems

As far as I know, one can create theorem environments using any of [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem), [`thmtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) and probably more.

How should I define my theorem environments? Is one package clearly superior? Which packages conflict? Is there one package that does everything? (For some reason I am using `ntheorem` but I cannot remember why).

For example, `thmtools` looks like it has some nice features, but I'm afraid of breaking my `ntheorem`-defined custom environments...

Comment: thmtools is not the package to do everything because it explicitly won't attempt something similar to ntheorems [thmmarks] option. (I don' think it can be done reliably without special cases to avoid conflict with other packages of hyperrefian dimensions.)

Comment: +1 for "hyperrefian".

Comment: It would be great to have answers talk about Mittelbach’s theorem.sty as well.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

To answer your question of whether `ntheorem` is clearly superior to `amsthm` (or the other way round), the answer is unfortunately no as both have advantages and shortcomings.

Feature-wise, `ntheorem` is clearly ahead of `amsthm`, but `amsthm` is more robustly designed, and has, as such, less bugs (of course, depending on how you use the `ntheorem` package, you may never encounter these bugs, but it's better to be aware of them).

**Comparison of features of ntheorem and amsthm**

The following table is inspired from the one given in the [French FAQ](http://www.grappa.univ-lille3.fr/FAQ-LaTeX/12.29.html) entry about theorem and shows a list of features of each packages, clearly showing that `ntheorem` can do more things than `amsthm`.

[image]

**Examples of ntheorem bugs**

Here are a few chosen bugs which can occur in ntheorem and of which you should be aware before deciding whether to use `ntheorem` or `amsthm`. All these bugs are specific to `ntheorem` and do not occur in `amsthm`.

***Break style clash with high material***

When using the break style, if you put something a little too high at the start of the theorem, it will overlap with the theorem title:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

***Footnote in theorem note***

While it may not be a very good pratice to put footnotes in theorem optional arguments, it can be needed some times, but doesn't work with `ntheorem` (the footnote text will be lost; you must use the \footnotemark/\footnotetext trick):

```
\begin{theorem}[Fermat's little theorem\footnote{First stated in a letter dated October 18, 1640.}]
...
\end{theorem}
```

***Long theorem note***

If the theorem's optional argument is too long (either because the document is in two column mode or because the note is indeed very long), it will hang out of the margin. Here's an example in two column mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{theorem}[A very very very very long optional argument]
\lipsum[2]
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

**Examples of amsthm bugs**

Although it has less bugs, `amsthm` is not completely bug-free. Here's a variant of the "too long theorem optional argument" `ntheorem` bug, but which only occurs with `amsthm` if a list is immediately following the theorem head:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{theorem}[A very very very very long optional argument]
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla bla bla.
\item Bla bla bla.
\item Bla bla bla.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[3-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: there is another bug (maybe) that is not mentioned: the indentation of the text following a ntheorem environment. The only way to get it not indented is to manually use a \noindent after each environment, which is very annoying. I do not know how to handle this. Otherwise, it is very convenient.

Comment: With `ntheorem`, if there isn't a blank line after `\end{theorem}`, the following paragraph will not be indented. On the other hand, `amsthm` will always indent the following paragraph, regardless of whether it is followed by a blank line or not (this is done by `\@endparenv` trickery). But this is a feature, not a bug: `amsthm` considers that a theorem is always a paragraph of its own, so the next one needs to be indented.

Comment: It might be worth also making the point the `ntheorem` conflicts with the AMS document classes was well...

Answer (score 19):

`ntheorem` interferes with `amsthm` but it provides some compatibility if you specify `amsthm` as option to `ntheorem`.

`ntheorem` is better in handling endmarks like `\qed` boxes or symbols, especially if an environment ends with a displayed formula and the endmark should be placed in line.

`thmtools` can be used additionally, it should work with either of the other theorem packages.

To sum up, using `thmtools` together with `ntheorem` could be the best choice especially if you need endmarks. Though I prefer `amsthm`, maybe because I'm used to its `\newtheoremstyle` macro.

Comment: Addendum: `thmtools` offers a key-value-syntax for the declaration of new theorem styles. It also allows for customized lists of theorems.

Comment: "Used to" is the most polite description I've ever heard with regards to the beast with 9 parameters. :)

Comment: I am in the middle of the job. Changing to \usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem} creates 914 errors and stops. It is difficult to resolve conflicts. It should be considered, if it must, at the beginning of the work.

Answer (score 6):

I like `ntheorem` together with `amsmath` a lot.  There *are* some wrinkles, however, which as far as I know have never been addressed.  One example that I run into frequently and have learned to just work around:  If (like me) you like to put your equation numbers on the left (i.e., using `leqno`), then you have to put the contents of an `equation` environment in a split, like this:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split} %% ntheorem kludge
     2 + 3 = 5
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

and you have to do the same thing if an equation is the last line of a proof. But other than a few irritations like that, I think `ntheorem` works very nicely.