# Weird behavior of ntheorem.

Tags: fonts, theorems

I have the following strange phenomena using ntheorem:

[Weird phenomena http://www.cgti.nl/gf/weird.png](http://www.cgti.nl/gf/weird.png)

I get $\Lambda$ instead of a `\box`. In other proofs I might get a `\box` or `\Lambda`. In the example I end with `\[ \]` if I use `equation` instead the box is not on the correct height.

This is the first part of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, leqno, draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm, mathtools, marvosym}
\usepackage[amsmath, amsthm, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
\usepackage{theoremref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyref}
```

A minimal example where this occurs:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, leqno, draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath, amsthm, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}

\theoremstyle{change}
\newcounter{acounter}[chapter]
\def\theacounter{\thechapter.\arabic{acounter}}
\newtheorem{lemma}[acounter]{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\[
f = g
\]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

How do I solve this? It seems like the problem is with `txfonts`.

Comment: Note that math expression like $\Lambda$ don't work here on TeX.SX as they do on Math.SX.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you, I have changed it to code.

Comment: Please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the undesired bahaviour.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Okay, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, the problem comes from `amsmath.sty` and `txfonts.sty` both defining the command `\openbox`.

Here's the definition in `txfonts.sty`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\openbox}{\begingroup \usefont{U}{txsya}{m}{n}\thr@@\endgroup}
```

and here's the definition in amsthm.sty:

```
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
```

One way to avoid the conflict would be to load `txfonts` *first* and then `amsthm` (as package option for `ntheorem`) and, with the help of the [savesym](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/savesym) package, rename the `\openbox` command from `txfonts` so that `\openbox` retains its `amsthm.sty` definition.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, leqno, draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{openbox}
\usepackage[amsthm,amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{change}
\newcounter{acounter}[chapter]
\def\theacounter{\thechapter.\arabic{acounter}}
\newtheorem{lemma}[acounter]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\[
f = g
\]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

As a side note, the `ntheorem` package documentation suggests the following:

> Thus, we recommend not to use amsthm,
>   since the features for defining
>   theorem- like environments in
>   ntheorem.sty—following
>   theorem.sty—seem to be more intu-
>   itive and user-friendly.

Of course, if you don't use the `amsthm` option you'll have to define your own `proof` environment.

EDIT: This suggestion has to be taken carefully: Philippe Goutet
has made an excellent comparison between `amsthm` and `ntheorem` in his answer to [Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/theorem-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict).

Comment: Great answer! I made my own `proof` environment and replaced the box by `\blackbox`.

Comment: Do you happen to know why `\[ \]` doesn't work anymore? The `equation*` environment however does work.

Comment: @Jonas T: I'll need to see a minimal working example to see your settings and be able to find the reason for the odd behaviour.

Comment: I think you mean that the `ntheorem` (not `amsthm`) documentation says not to use `amsthm` anymore. And that's not quite true, as `ntheorem` has a few bugs which `amsthm` has not, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/theorem-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict

Comment: @Philippe Goutet: yes, it was `ntheorem` documentation; fixed. I (until today) understood the quote as recommending not to use `amsthm` *together* with `ntheorem`; however, now that I reread it, it seems, in fact, to suggest not to use `amsthm` anymomore, and I don't agree with this. Thank you for noticing this and for the link.