# Linebreak in definition heading (theorem package)

Tags: line-breaking, theorems

I have a problem with a too long line in the theorem environment. The following example shows the problem, I need a line break in the heading, but there is none. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{theorem}
{\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
 \theorembodyfont{\normalfont\slshape}
 \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Long heading that should have a line break]
A definition is a statement of the meaning of a term (a word, phrase, or other set of symbols).
Definitions can be classified into two large categories, intensional definitions (which try to give the essence of a term) and extensional definitions (which list every single object that a term describes).
A term may have many different senses and multiple meanings, and thus require multiple definitions.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

With the help of another topic I found a solution myself, if anyone is interested, the solution is below. I switched the package "theorem" with "ntheorem" and added some formation commands, which I adapted from another topic:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}% Adds automatic line break, if heading is too long
  {\item{\theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}~}
  {\item{\theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator}~}
\makeatother

{\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
 \theorembodyfont{\normalfont\slshape}
 \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Long heading that should have a line break]
A definition is a statement of the meaning of a term (a word, phrase, or other set of symbols).
Definitions can be classified into two large categories, intensional definitions (which try to give the essence of a term) and extensional definitions (which list every single object that a term describes).
A term may have many different senses and multiple meanings, and thus require multiple definitions.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note 1: Can some mod please mark this as solved? (Or delete it, if this is an uninteresting question.) I somehow wasn't able to login first so I asked this question as guest and now found a solution myself.

Note 2: This solution is different compared to the ones already present in this forum! [This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26042/how-can-i-get-a-line-break-in-a-theorem-headline)  does not work with theorem package and [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79145/line-break-in-theorem-header?rq=1) requires eight more lines of code plus the result is different (I don't want a line break AFTER the heading just INSIDE the heading).