# Line break in starred ntheorem header

Tags: line-breaking, tufte, ntheorem

I came across [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79145/line-break-in-theorem-header) that was posted before and have been using the solution for a while. However, I can't seem to get the same thing to work with starred environments.

I am aware that long theorem titles have been a long-standing bug with `ntheorem`. However, some pointers as to how I can workaround this, if there exists one such workaround out there, is appreciated.

The following is a MWE using the tufte class, just to stay consistent with my usual setup.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

% Workaround for long titles in ntheorem
\makeatletter
\let\nobreakitem\item
\let\@nobreakitem\@item
\patchcmd{\nobreakitem}{\@item}{\@nobreakitem}{}{}
\patchcmd{\nobreakitem}{\@item}{\@nobreakitem}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@nobreakitem}{\@itempenalty}{\@M}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@xthm}{\ignorespaces}{\nobreak\ignorespaces}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@ythm}{\ignorespaces}{\nobreak\ignorespaces}{}{}

\renewtheoremstyle{break}%
  {\item{\theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hskip\labelsep\relax\nobreakitem}%
  {\item{\theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator}\hskip\labelsep\relax\nobreakitem}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremprework{\textcolor{magenta}{\hrule height 2pt width \textwidth}}
\theoremheaderfont{\color{magenta}\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorempostwork{\textcolor{magenta}{\hrule height 2pt width \textwidth}}
\theoremindent10pt
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremprework{\textcolor{magenta}{\hrule height 2pt width \textwidth}}
\theoremheaderfont{\color{magenta}\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorempostwork{\textcolor{magenta}{\hrule height 2pt width \textwidth}}
\theoremindent10pt
\newtheorem*{theoremn}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem]
  This is a numbered theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theoremn}[Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem]
  This is an unnumbered theorem.
\end{theoremn}
\end{document}
```

The following is an image of how it looks like:
[image: Numbered theorem vs Unnumbered theorem]

For those who intend to recommend `amsthm`, note that I cannot achieve the styling of theorem environments that I can do with `ntheorem`, which is why I would prefer to find a solution with `ntheorem`, rather than dropping it. Also, the use of frames (e.g. `mdframed`) is a no-go, since I am also using the tufte class, and I greatly rely on having ample side notes and margin notes in my documents.

Comment: Was not sure how helpful it would be, especially since it is very similar to the linked problem, but I have added an MWE anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```latex
\def\thm@nonumberbreak{%
  \def\@begintheorem##1##2{%
    \item
    {\theorem@headerfont##1\theorem@separator}
    \hskip\labelsep\relax\nobreakitem 
  }%
  \def\@opargbegintheorem##1##2##3{%
    \item 
    {\theorem@headerfont##1\ (##3)\theorem@separator}%
    \hskip\labelsep\relax\nobreakitem 
  }%
}
```

before `\makeatother`. More simply, use `regexpatch` instead of `etoolbox`.

```latex
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

% Workaround for long titles in ntheorem
\makeatletter
\let\nobreakitem\item
\let\@nobreakitem\@item
\xpatchcmd{\nobreakitem}{\@item}{\@nobreakitem}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\nobreakitem}{\@item}{\@nobreakitem}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@nobreakitem}{\@itempenalty}{\@M}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@xthm}{\ignorespaces}{\nobreak\ignorespaces}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@ythm}{\ignorespaces}{\nobreak\ignorespaces}{}{}

\renewtheoremstyle{break}%
  {\item{\theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hskip\labelsep\relax\nobreakitem}%
  {\item{\theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator}\hskip\labelsep\relax\nobreakitem}
% make \th@nonumberbreak the same as \th@break, but remove "\ ##2"
\let\th@nonumberbreak\th@break
\xpatchcmd*{\th@nonumberbreak}{\ ##2}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremprework{\textcolor{magenta}{\hrule height 2pt width \textwidth}}
\theoremheaderfont{\color{magenta}\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorempostwork{\textcolor{magenta}{\hrule height 2pt width \textwidth}}
\theoremindent10pt
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremprework{\textcolor{magenta}{\hrule height 2pt width \textwidth}}
\theoremheaderfont{\color{magenta}\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorempostwork{\textcolor{magenta}{\hrule height 2pt width \textwidth}}
\theoremindent10pt
\newtheorem*{theoremn}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem]
  This is a numbered theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theoremn}[Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem Theorem]
  This is an unnumbered theorem.
\end{theoremn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are the theorem headings meant to be ragged right?

Comment: Thank you. How does one go about learning how to tackle these problems on their own? Mind sharing some of your insight to help a learning fellow? I am aware that this is not the best place for these sort of questions but I am out of my wit.

Comment: @Japorized I just noticed a bunch of `\vbox` and `\hbox` in the definition of `\th@nonumberbreak`; then I looked at `\th@break` and thought that it ought to be similar. I never use `ntheorem` because it's rather inflexible.