# theorem header still not breaking line

Tags: line-breaking

The question has been asked before at [How can I get a line break in a theorem headline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26042/how-can-i-get-a-line-break-in-a-theorem-headline), but the answers seem not to work for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}%[a4paper,oneside]
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false,
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{itteerde.bib}
\bibliography{itteerde} 

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{zeit}{Zeit-online}


\begin{document}


\section{2016-02-22}

\begin{zeit}[A long title as a heading for some commentary at more and longer and now or somewhere it should be broken up instead of leaving the page and it sucks?]
    \begin{quote}[Waldeule]
        ...
    \end{quote}

    Die...
\end{zeit}

Text...

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you know the question has been asked before, please link the relevant thread.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26042/how-can-i-get-a-line-break-in-a-theorem-headline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `amsthm` there's nothing special to do in order that the “attribution” part (that is, the optional argument) splits across lines.

The problem, in your case, is the `quote` environment just at the start. An obscure feature, I'd say. Just add `\mbox{}` so the `quote` is seen after the attribution has been typeset.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{zeit}{Zeit-online}


\begin{document}

\begin{zeit}[A long title as a heading for some commentary at more and longer and
  now or somewhere it should be broken up instead of leaving the page and it sucks?]
\mbox{}
\begin{quote}
A quotation of something
\end{quote}
Some text for the theorem.
\end{zeit}

Some text after the theorem.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no idea why this is how it is but thx, works.

Comment: @user60625 `\begin{zeit}` and `\begin{quote}` fight each other trying to do similar things. As I said, it's a quite obscure feature. You'd get the same with `center` instead of `quote`: every environment directly based on `trivlist` has the defect.