# Is there a guide to the various theorem packages?

Tags: packages, theorems, incompatibility, tufte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/theorem-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict)

I'm relatively new to LaTeX, and a complete novice when it comes to theorems in LaTeX. But I need to put some some theorems in my documents, and am unsure where to begin. Which of the many packages should I use?

My concerns are

- compatibility going forward, e.g. with packages and versions of LaTeX in active development,
- flexibility and customizability, especially of numbering, referencing, and formatting, and
- compatibility with other packages I use, esp. Tufte-LaTeX, `mathdesign`, `prettyref` (and perhaps eventually `cleverref`, `mathtools`, and `tikz`.

I'm not (as) concerned with backwards compatibility (e.g. with AMS document classes).

Is there a guide available for the various theorem packages that gives an overview of their use and of their capabilities, strengths and weaknesses, and development status?

Comment: How about [theorem-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/theorem-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict)

Comment: [There certainly is](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5599/215) and searching for "theorem packages conflict" on this very site would have found it for you.

Comment: @Seamus: Yes, that lacks much of a treatment of `thmtools` features, or information about development status, or incompatibilities with other packages, or how the packages fit in with active development directions.

Comment: The best place to find out about `thmtools` features would be the `thmtools` manual. I don't know what an "active development direction" is. Sounds like management speak…

Comment: @Seamus: Sorry, it refers to the question: compatibility "with packages and versions of LaTeX in active development". For example are some theorem packages more or less likely to break in LaTeX3; or which are expected to see significant updates in the next TeX distribution, etc.

Comment: @Seamus: Sorry this isn't a duplicate. The question is quiet different. What I'm askign is, in effect, is there, for example, a book chapter or white paper that reviews the packages, discusses their strengthes and weaknesses, capabilities, use by various bodies (like the AMA) or publications, level of current support, history of development, etc. Compatability is onle one of the things that might be discussed in such a guide. The answer may be "no", but the question is not a diplicate.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius The answers to the above linked question probably provide the best overview of the features of the various theorem packages. The answers to that question are not all about compatibility.

Comment: @Seamus: So more like a duplicate answer than a duplicate question (but I see your point).