# Environments with thmtools => too much space if using itemize at the end (also problem with q.e.d. symbol)

Tags: spacing, environments, paragraphs, itemize, thmtools

I want to use the `thmtools` package, because it provides some awesome features for declaring environments (proofs, theorems, examples etc.)

And I especially like the "qed" feature which places some nice symbols like the q.e.d. square at the end of the environments. For example, I am using different symbols for different environments.

However, there are some issues, if I use special blocks (itemize, align) at the end of such an environment. The "qed" symbol is too low and much space is wasted.

Test the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[headpunct=\\*,qed=\ensuremath{\triangle}]{myexstyle} 
\declaretheorem[style=myexstyle]{myexample} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{myexample}[This is an example 1]
This is an example...

And the symbol is on the correct line!
\end{myexample} 

\begin{myexample}[This is an example 2]
This is an another example...
\begin{itemize}
  \item And the symbol is \emph{not} on the correct line!
\end{itemize}
\end{myexample} 

\end{document}
```

I want that the `\triangle` is shown on the same line as the last `\item`.

I already fixed that problem for `align` environments (I am using package `adjustbox` und `aligned` now), but I cannot solve the problem, if I want to use `itemize` the way shown.

I think that I also know the reason for the problem. `\end{itemize}` ends the paragraph and a new paragraph must be started in order to place the "qed" symbol.

Is there an option? A Workaround? Preferably without `\qedhere` or manual adjustments for each environment! I was also wondering if package `enumitem` (or another one) could be helpful with any kind of option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with the endmarks in `amsthm` is a well known issue; the following remark is from the documentation:

> Placement of the QED symbol can be problematic if the last part of a
>   `proof` environment is a displayed equation or list environment or
>   something of that nature. In that case put a `\qedhere` command at the
>   place where the QED symbol should appear...

So one option is to manually put `\qedhere`:

```
\begin{myexample}[This is an example 2]
This is an another example...
\begin{itemize}
  \item And the symbol is on the correct line!\qedhere
\end{itemize}
\end{myexample}
```

However, you said you don't want to manually use `\qedhere`, then I am afraid that using `amsthm` is not the best choice. One option would be to use `ntheorem` as the back-end for `thmtools` instead of `amsthm`, since the former  solves the problem of setting endmarks of theorem-like environments automatically at the right positions (even if the environment ends with a displaymath or list environment).

Now, you have to make a choice: either you stick to `amsthm` and accept having to manually put `\qedhere` under some circumstances, or you switch to `ntheorem`; perhaps [Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5599/3954) can help you to make a decision.

Here's your example but now using `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headpunct={},
qed=\ensuremath{\triangle},
bodyfont=\normalfont
]{myexstyle} 
\declaretheorem[style=break]{myexample} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{myexample}[This is an example 1]
This is an example...

And the symbol is on the correct line!
\end{myexample} 

\begin{myexample}[This is an example 2]
This is an another example...
\begin{itemize}
  \item And the symbol is on the correct line!
\end{itemize}
\end{myexample} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the note for the title appears boldfaced; unfortunately, the `notefont` key for `thmtools` is not supported with `ntheorem`, so if you want to change the note font, you will have to add the following to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{break}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\ {\normalfont(##3)}\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Ok, I understand now that both amsthm and ntheorem can be used as backend. I have known that already, but forgot after one year. I have also had many problems one year ago. However, I tried again, and thanks to your tips, it really works better then with amsthm. However, one must know that some special is required. For example (as I have seen in your example) `declaretheoremstyle` can be used, but must be placed directly before each `declaretheorem`. Usable options are different as well (and much less)! However, after some research I found each option I needed. Thanks!