# How to set \qedhere properly within "alignat*" environment?

Tags: amsmath, amsthm, alignat

The last part of my proof is formatted in an `alignat*` environment. How do I make `\qedhere` appear correctly?

The naive approach (as you would do with `align*`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
      &\quad& f &\le g \\
      \implies && f-a &\le g-a \\
      \implies && b(f-a) &\le b(g-a)
      \qedhere
    \end{alignat*}
  \end{proof}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

produces an undesired result and the following warning:

```
The \qedhere command may not work correctly here
```

Comment: If you use `ntheorem` this is automatic. Actually, you don't have to type `\qedhere`: `\end{proof}` is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing to do is to add some final words to conclude the proof. If this is not an option, then some trickery would be required; here, using `\tag*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
      &\quad& f &\le g \\
      \implies && f-a &\le g-a
      \tag*{\qedhere}
    \end{alignat*}
  \end{proof}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The [`ntheorem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package claims to have a better management of the QED symbol, however, it doesn't give an out of the box `proof` environment unless the amsthm option is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
      &\quad& f &\le g \\
      \implies && f-a &\le g-a
    \end{alignat*}
  \end{proof}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

so no need for `\qedhere` in this case and the placement is correct. However, take into account the accepted answer to [`Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict?`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5599/3954) and ponder whether to change to `ntheorem`.

Comment: Neat trick. However, I get a steady warning about \linegoal, even after the 3rd and 4th run of LaTeX. What's going wrong here? Can the example be improved to run without persistent warnings?

Comment: @vog You're right. I updated my answer with a simpler option (and no warnings).

Comment: I didn't switch to ntheorem, but went along with the `\tag*{\qedhere}` solution. Neat trick!

Answer (score 2):

if you're willing to make a manual adjustment, a modification of the
`\qedhere` mechanism will work.  (the value of the negative `\vspace` may
need some adjustment depending on local conditions.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
      &\quad& f &\le g \\
      \implies && f-a &\le g-a \\
      \implies && b(f-a) &\le b(g-a)
    \end{alignat*}
    \par \vspace{-1.7\baselineskip}
    \qedhere
  \end{proof}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

the idea for this approach was inspired by @egreg.

Comment: What is the advantage to the `\tag*{\qedhere}` solution presented in Gonzalo Medina's answer?

Comment: @vog -- both approaches to this problem should work.  it probably comes down to personal taste.  the `\tag*` approach may be more reliable, in that, when you're at the bottom of a page, there is no likelihood that the tombstone will break to the new page, whereas there's a small chance that the `\par \vspace` might; putting `\nobreak` right after `\par` should help guard against that, but i haven't tested it thoroughly.  (i really should.)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `\qedhere` doesn't work with `alignat` should be considered as a bug of `amsmath`.

However, in this case you don't need `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
         &\quad& f &\le g \\
\implies && f-a &\le g-a
\qedhere
\end{alignat*}
\end{proof}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
                f &\le g \\
\implies\quad f-a &\le g-a  \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

As you see, the alignment in the second `proof` environment is the same as in the first one.

However, `\qedhere` should be used sparingly and ending a proof with a math display is not the best choice.

[image]

Comment: Good point. I improved by MWE to make clear why I need `alignat*` instead of `align*`

Comment: i've marked this question for attention when i get back to the office and can do some testing.  however, it's not generally recommended to start a proof directly with a display.  (there are known problems when a proof is started with `itemize` or `enumerate`, and i suspect this is related.)  so that is a condition to be tested.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The beginning of the proof is irrelevant. The same issue happens when the proof starts with a paragraph (as it does in my real use case, I just left it out for the MWE).