# Gettting rid of ntheorem's limitation concerning footnotes in theorem's notes

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, amsthm, optional-arguments, ntheorem

As shown by the following MWE, footnotes in theorems' notes work well for `amsthm`'s theorems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Foo\footnote{Bar.}]
Baz.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

but, as shown by the following M**N**WE and according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5633/18401), not for `ntheorem`'s theorems where the footnote texts are lost and the `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext` trick is required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Foo\footnote{Bar.}]
Baz.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Foo\footnotemark]
  \footnotetext{Bar.}
Baz.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

While it may not be a very good practice to put footnotes in theorem optional arguments, it could be useful in some cases, e.g. for citations in footnote as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
% \usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[\citeauthor{knuth:ct}\footcite{knuth:ct}]
Baz.
\end{theorem}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For some reasons, I'm stick to `ntheorem` and can't change it for `amsthm`. Any hope of a workaround to this `ntheorem`'s limitation?

Comment: There *are* reasons why I prefer `amsthm`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Without its limitations, you would prefer `ntheorem`, don't you? ;)

Comment: Not at all. ;-)

Comment: @egreg But, as pointed out in the linked answer, `ntheorem` can do more things (and interesting things) than `amsthm`: `ntheorem` *is* cool! :)

Comment: No, I don't agree; I can add endmarks very easily to environments created by `amsthm` and `\qedhere` usually performs better than the machinery set up by `ntheorem` to make it automatic. Anyway, the limitation is due to using `\item[...]` for typesetting the theorem label (including the note). You can reproduce the issue with `\begin{enumerate}\item[x\footnote{y}]\end{enumerate}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to load the `footnote` package and, thanks to its `\makesavenoteenv` command, to ask for the (`ntheorem`'s) theorems to handle footnotes correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\makesavenoteenv{theorem}
\makesavenoteenv{lemma}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[\citeauthor{knuth:ct}\footcite{knuth:ct}]
Baz.
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}[\citeauthor{knuth:ct}\footcite{knuth:ct}]
Baz.
\end{lemma}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `footnote` has been unmaintained for several years and that it can introduce issues with other packages.