# When I type \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]it doesn't compile! I am guessing it has to do with the package I am using

Tags: math-mode, theorems

```
%\documentclass[manuscript]{biometrika}
\documentclass[lineno]{biometrika}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%% Please use the following statements for
%% managing the text and math fonts for your papers:
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage[cmbold]{mathtime}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[plain,noend]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} 
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
} 
\def\roundloop[#1]#2#3{%
 \coordinate (rla) at (#2.east); 
 \path   (#2)--++(#1) coordinate (rlb);
 \tkzTgtFromP(#2,rla)(rlb)            
 \node (rlb) at (rlb) [circle through={(tkzFirstPointResult)}] {};
 \coordinate  (rlc) at (intersection 2 of #2 and rlb);
 \coordinate  (rld) at (intersection 1 of #2 and rlb);         
 \tikzAngleOfLine(rlb)(rld){\AngleStart}
 \tikzAngleOfLine(rlb)(rlc){\AngleEnd} 
 \tikzAngleOfLine(#2)(rlb){\AngleLabel}
 \ifdim\AngleStart pt<\AngleEnd pt
 \draw[red,thick,->]%
   let \p1 = ($ (rlb) - (rld) $), \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
   in   
     (rlb) ++(\AngleLabel:\n2) node[fill=white]{#3}
     (rld) arc (\AngleStart:\AngleEnd:\n2); 
 \else 
  \draw[black,thick,->]%
   let \p1 = ($ (rlb) - (rld) $), \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
   in   
     (rlb) ++(\AngleLabel:\n2) node[fill=white]{#3}
     (rld) arc (\AngleStart-360:\AngleEnd:\n2); 
   \fi 
  }
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@captiontext}[2]{#1\algocf@typo. \AlCapFnt{}#2} % text of caption
\renewcommand{\AlTitleFnt}[1]{#1\unskip}% default definition
\def\@algocf@capt@plain{top}
\renewcommand{\algocf@makecaption}[2]{%
  \addtolength{\hsize}{\algomargin}%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\algocf@captiontext{#1}{#2}}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa >\hsize%     % if caption is longer than a line
    \hskip .5\algomargin%
    \parbox[t]{\hsize}{\algocf@captiontext{#1}{#2}}% then caption is not centered
  \else%
    \global\@minipagefalse%
    \hbox to\hsize{\box\@tempboxa}% else caption is centered
  \fi%
  \addtolength{\hsize}{-\algomargin}%
}

\makeatother

%%% User-defined macros should be placed here, but keep them to a minimum.
\def\Bka{{\it Biometrika}}
\def\AIC{\textsc{aic}}
\def\T{{ \mathrm{\scriptscriptstyle T} }}
\def\v{{\varepsilon}}

\begin{document}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{definition}

The \textit{moment generating function} (MGF) of a random variable $T$ is defined by 

\begin{equation}

M_T(s)=E(e^{sT})=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{st}f_T(t)dt,

\end{equation}

provided that $M_T$ exists for $s \in (-a,a)$ and some $a > 0$.

\end{definition}
\end{document]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you extend this to a [minimal (not quite) working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  Adding in `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` with an example of the `\newtheorem` command which leads to the error.  Is the `biometrika` class sourced from http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/biomet/for_authors/ if not please link to the source.

Comment: See the edited example above

Comment: Blank lines are not allowed in the `equation` environment and there is a typo in `\end{document]` which should be `\end{document}`.  Making these corrections and using the `article` class rather than `biometrika` I can compile your code.  If after making these changes it does not compile with the `biometrika` class then there's probably a conflict between your preamble and the class file.

Comment: The `biometrika` class seems to load the [`ntheorem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package which can conflict with [`amsthm`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) according to [Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5599/106162)  Try removing `\usepackage{amsthm}` and placing `\PassOptionsToPackage{amsthm}{ntheorem}` before `\documentclass`.  Also you load the `amsmath` package twice.

Answer (score 5):

This answer uses the `biometrika` class (and related files) from http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/biomet/for_authors/

There are a few errors in the MWE, `\end{document]` should be `\end{document}` and the blank lines in the `equation` environment will causes errors.  The `amsmath` package is also loaded twice.  Correcting these errors and using the `article` class rather than `biometrika` will enable compilation.

The `biometrika` class however leads to further issues.  The `biometrika` class calls the [`ntheorem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package which has some conflicts with [`amsthm`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), removing the [`amsthm`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package leaves one further error, that the `definition` theorem is already defined by the `biometrika` class, removing the line `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]` allows compilation (this is to be advised as the `definition` environment will therefore appear as the journal wants).

Thus using the following example I am able to compile the OP's MWE

```
%\documentclass[manuscript]{biometrika}
\documentclass[lineno]{biometrika}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%% Please use the following statements for
%% managing the text and math fonts for your papers:
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage[cmbold]{mathtime}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[plain,noend]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} 
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
} 
\def\roundloop[#1]#2#3{%
 \coordinate (rla) at (#2.east); 
 \path   (#2)--++(#1) coordinate (rlb);
 \tkzTgtFromP(#2,rla)(rlb)            
 \node (rlb) at (rlb) [circle through={(tkzFirstPointResult)}] {};
 \coordinate  (rlc) at (intersection 2 of #2 and rlb);
 \coordinate  (rld) at (intersection 1 of #2 and rlb);         
 \tikzAngleOfLine(rlb)(rld){\AngleStart}
 \tikzAngleOfLine(rlb)(rlc){\AngleEnd} 
 \tikzAngleOfLine(#2)(rlb){\AngleLabel}
 \ifdim\AngleStart pt<\AngleEnd pt
 \draw[red,thick,->]%
   let \p1 = ($ (rlb) - (rld) $), \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
   in   
     (rlb) ++(\AngleLabel:\n2) node[fill=white]{#3}
     (rld) arc (\AngleStart:\AngleEnd:\n2); 
 \else 
  \draw[black,thick,->]%
   let \p1 = ($ (rlb) - (rld) $), \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
   in   
     (rlb) ++(\AngleLabel:\n2) node[fill=white]{#3}
     (rld) arc (\AngleStart-360:\AngleEnd:\n2); 
   \fi 
  }
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@captiontext}[2]{#1\algocf@typo. \AlCapFnt{}#2} % text of caption
\renewcommand{\AlTitleFnt}[1]{#1\unskip}% default definition
\def\@algocf@capt@plain{top}
\renewcommand{\algocf@makecaption}[2]{%
  \addtolength{\hsize}{\algomargin}%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\algocf@captiontext{#1}{#2}}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa >\hsize%     % if caption is longer than a line
    \hskip .5\algomargin%
    \parbox[t]{\hsize}{\algocf@captiontext{#1}{#2}}% then caption is not centered
  \else%
    \global\@minipagefalse%
    \hbox to\hsize{\box\@tempboxa}% else caption is centered
  \fi%
  \addtolength{\hsize}{-\algomargin}%
}

\makeatother

%%% User-defined macros should be placed here, but keep them to a minimum.
\def\Bka{{\it Biometrika}}
\def\AIC{\textsc{aic}}
\def\T{{ \mathrm{\scriptscriptstyle T} }}
\def\v{{\varepsilon}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}

The \textit{moment generating function} (MGF) of a random variable $T$ is defined by 

\begin{equation}
M_T(s)=E(e^{sT})=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{st}f_T(t)dt,
\end{equation}

provided that $M_T$ exists for $s \in (-a,a)$ and some $a > 0$.

\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

The [`ntheorem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package advertises that it can be made more compatible with [`amsth`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) by passing the `amsthm` option to the [`ntheorem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package ([`amsthm`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) should not be loaded for this).  This can be passed to [`ntheorem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) by placing `\PassOptionsToPackage{amsthm}{ntheorem}` before `\documentclass` although this does not seem to be necessary to make the code given by the OP compilable.