# How to draw side-by-side boxes in a flowchart using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, flow-charts

How can I draw this figure centered within the following code

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{url}\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
\usepackage {tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{parts}
    \part \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[rectangle,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=5cm] (m) {
       \begin{minipage}{1.95cm}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,5) node[minimum width=0.9cm, minimum height=0.9cm,draw] {$a$};
            \draw (0,5) -> (1,5) node[minimum width=0.9cm, minimum height=0.9cm] {$a$};
          \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
      };
      \draw[dashed] (m.south west) rectangle (m.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{parts}
\end{document}
```

and this is the image that a make

[image]

[image: And this]

Comment: What *exactly* are you having difficulties with?  You are only showing some images.  Questions seeking formatting help ("**how to make this image?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: If you don't know where to start, take a look at these questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5599 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205

Comment: I'm sorry, the question would be how to draw this image in latex https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc3aN.png , because I have had difficulties with handling the tikz library

Comment: Start from the template `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}\end{document}` and read through the tutorials on the first pages of the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).  As you get stuck, post the code here and explain what you try to achieve.  Keep the question as *specific* as possible.

Comment: What does the `parts` environment do and what does `\part`, which is a sectioning command, have to do with the image? Do you want this to appear on a kind of part title page or something? If you're not familiar with `\part`, I'd suggest starting with an introduction to LaTeX before trying to learn Ti*k*Z.

Comment: *Which* Ti*k*Z library did you have trouble with? *What* trouble did you have with it? There are many, many libraries built-in, without mentioning the third-party additions.

Comment: @HenriMenke You think the OP is asking about a theorem/`amsthm`/`ntheorem`? Admittedly, the `parts` thing is really unclear.

Comment: @cfr See the question history.  There was a theorem-like thing in the first version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as exercise for me and starting point for you :)

[image]

pure `tikz` image, needed libraries `arrows.meta`, `fit`, `positioning`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, fit, positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 8mm and 4mm,
         F/.style = {draw, rounded corners, dash dot,
                     label=$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}_{#1}}$
                     }
                    ]
\node (n1) [draw]           {a};
\node (n2) [right=of n1]    {a};
\node (n3) [below=of n2]    {b};
%
\node (n4)  [below right = 2mm and 22mm of n3]  {x};
\node (n5)  [below=of n4]                       {y};
%
\node (n6)  [below left = 2mm and 22mm of n5]   {c};
\node (n7)  [below=of n6]                       {d};
%%
\node [F=3,
      fit=(n1) (n7)] {};
\node [F=4, minimum width=8mm,
      fit=(n1.north -| n4) (n7.south -| n5)] {};
%%
\draw[semithick,-Latex] (n1) edge (n2)
                        (n2) edge (n3)
                        (n4) edge (n5)
                        (n6)  to  (n7);
\draw[semithick,densely dashed,-{Latex[fill=white]}]
                        (n3) edge (n4)
                        (n5) edge (n6);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```